# Is it possible to find the source of a downloaded pdf file from examining the pdf itself?

Tags: pdf, file-download

Is it possible to find out the source of a downloaded pdf from examining the pdf data? The pdf in question was not downloaded by myself but was downloaded into an account of mine. I have since changed passwords.
From opening the pdf it appears to be a website saved as a pdf format.

Comment: Mobiles are off-topic.

Comment: Thank you David, I will modify my question to suit.

Comment: you want to know the website it came from? expand on *source* please, what exactly do you want to know?

Answer (score 3):

If you downloaded to an NTFS drive, the source may be recorded in an alternate data stream called 'Zone:Identifier'.

[image]

An easy way to find and view alternate data streams is [Nirsoft's AlternateStreamView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/alternate_data_streams.html).

Answer (score 2):

Unless the origin is "*in*" the PDF (i.e: as Text or Metadata), there is no way to know where it came from...

In addition to this, any origin that **appears** to be in the PDF may not actually relate to the *perceived* origin.

For example:

- The file may have been produced by an academic at a University
- There may be a link to the author's web space on the University systems, or even a direct link to the PDF
- But you may have actually downloaded it from a mirror or some other random site

---

Fundamentally: browsers do not modify file content, so there is no way to know where a file was actually retrieved from. Your best option is the browser history.

At a pinch you could try searching for text in the PDF to see if the results refresh your memory.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible & is very easy also. Works for me always as I am using latest version of adobe acrobat.

> **STEP 1:**
> Open the pdf against which you want to check the details.

> **STEP 2:**
> Once the pdf is open right click anywhere on the screen of the pdf & then select "**document properties**" (adobe acrobat should be used)

> **STEP 3:**
> Select "**description tab**" from the popped up windows & there you will find all the relevant data like created title, author, created on, modified on, application used to make that pdf, application used for the coding etc.

Comment: Note that the data indicated there is whatever was entered by the creator or previous editor, and does not necessarily reflect accurate data.